# Does javascript string replace create a new string if no replacement happened?

Tags: javascript, string

```
    let s = 'ABC';
    s = s.replace('D', 'E');
```

Is `s` the same string (in the memory aspect, not it's value) after this?

According to the MDN, it says the return value is  `A new string, with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement.`, but I'd like to know if the special case with "NO" matches would return the original string without creating a new one.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in Javascript so the variable will now point to a new reference in memory with the new value. However the previous value will still exist in the old location in memory until it is garbage collected.

Comment: So after calling `replace`, there are 2 parts of memory containing `ABC`? i.e. Does `replace` allocate new memory to contain the new string no matter what? And do you know any reference website stating these details? Thanks

Comment: Yes. Replace will cause new memory to be allocated for the new string. The closest resource I can find is MDN's doc on mutable. They have a string example that discusses this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Mutable